# Numbers of object created during serialization using writeUnshared()

Tags: java, serialization, io

I played a little bit with Serialization lately in order to be prepared for the OCPJP7 exam.
I hence tried to serialize the following class:

```
class TempClass  implements Serializable {  
        int secCounter;   
        static int counter;  
        {  
                counter++;  
        }  
        {  
        secCounter=counter;
```

then when I try to write the object to a `FileOutputStream` with the following:

```
TempClass temp = new TempClass();  
ObjectOutputStream obi = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));   
obi.writeObject(temp);  
obi.writeUnshared(temp);  
obi.writeUnshared(temp);
```

So here I get 3 different objects when I read them back with an `ObjectInputStream`, therefore 3 objects have been created.
However the final value of `secCounter`, which is an instance variable so can be serialized, is 1 instead of 3.
1 is the number of time I called the `new` keyword, So I supposed the constructor gets handled in a different way when an object is created with `obi.writeUnshared(object)`.
Does anybody know what exactly happens? I know that static variables are not serialized however in the above posted code I copied the value from the static variable to the instance variable `secCounter`.
So again eventually checking the value of `secCounter` which is serialized successfully won't get me the expected (at least to me) result but 1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nimbers of objects created during serialization ...

***Zero*** objects are created during serialization, for the purposes of this question.

> therefore 3 objects have been created.

No objects are created by writeUnshared(). Objects are created when *deserializing.*

> However the final value of secCounter, which is an instance variable so can be serialized, is 1 instead of 3.

Proves the point. No objects are created when serializing.

> 1 is the number of time I called the new keyword, So I supposed the constructor gets handled in a different way when an object is created with obi.writeUnshared()

Once again, no objects are created by this method. No constructor is called. What *doesn't* happen in writeUnshared() is serialization of a 'handle' to an existing serialized object. The object *as it is now* is serialized, instead of a handle that will be deserialized as a reference to a previously deserialized instance.

Comment: Problem is when he reads them back, not when he is serializing.

Comment: @EJP however when I read them back they have different toString() therefore are different objects.. and yet even with the last read one, th value of secCounter is still 1.

Comment: @Rolerball Exactly. You are confused about when the 'replication' or 'cloning' or 'construction' happens. It doesn't happen at the sender, or via construction, so the code you are expecting to be executed doesn't execute.

Comment: @EJP However the final result is that I have 3 different objects. I am aware how the first one got created, I did with "new". What about the other two? When do they get created? I am talking about the ones serialized with write.Unshared() and then read back and put in a reference.

Comment: I've answered that. During *deserialization.*

Comment: @EJP and Deserialization creates a new object without calling the constructor and initializers. cool thanks now I see

Comment: @Rollerball Exactly. Perhaps you need to have a look at the Object Serialization Specification.

Answer (score 0):

During deserialization constructors (or initializers, like in your case) are not executed, this is because when you deserialize an object you highly probably expect the internal state of the object being the same as the state of the original object. Running initializers or constructors could have "side effects" like modifying the internal state of your object.

Comment: So what would be the advantage of having a new (yet the same) object? Would not it be better to just use writeObject(ob) which does not create a clone?

Comment: @Rollerball writeUnshared() doesn't 'create a clone' either. Your understanding of the process is badly flawed.

Comment: @EJP ok I should have "" the word clone.. did not mean clone as the same as using clone() method, My bad sorry about that. However I mean another object with the same state of the one "shared" hence written by writeObject rather than writeUnshared

Comment: If you deserialize with `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` you will have "clones" of the object (objects with equal internal state), perhaps that's the reason of having writeUnshared, but I'm not sure about that one to be honest.

Comment: @Rollerball You need to understand the difference between what you wrote and what you now say you meant. No creation occurs when sending, ergo no value change occurs.

Comment: @morgano You will not have 'clones of the object'. You will have either different references to the same object (writeObject()) or different objects (writeUnshared()). If you're 'not sure' about this, please don't just add to the confusion.

Comment: @EJP I think it is clear that when we say "clones" in this discusion we refer to objects with identical internal state. What I'm not sure about is about the advantages of "writeUnshared()", not about my answer. As it seems you are an expert on the subject you could improve your answer by explaining such "advantages"

Comment: @morgano The OP didn't ask about 'advantages'. He asked how many objects get created during serialization. I've answered that. You're just creating noise. If you want to know about advantages, ask the question, or better still read the Javadoc, or indeed my answer.

Comment: @EJP Please read the first comment the OP left on my answer, that's what I was refering to when I said "I'm not sure", he asked why don't just using writeObject()

Comment: That's a comment on your answer, not part of the original question, and it's therefore addressed to you, not to me or the general public. If you wish to answer it, don't let me stop you.